# Sencha Touch 2 - Text Overlapping Issue

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm a new developer in Sencha Touch 2 and I'm trying to create my first application using its provided MVC architecture. I find issues with toolbar/titlebar text overlapping when navigating between pages. Take a look at these screenshots:

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrhn5.png)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwWVE.png)

I'm not pretty sure what's happening out there. I am using animateActiveItem and routing method to move across my application.

**Users.js controller file, login method**

```
// Ajax code here, not included here
// on ajax success:
this.redirectTo("login");
```

**Routes.js controller file**

```
routeLoginPage: function() {
    console.log("routeLoginPage");
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem({ xtype: "loginpage" }, { type: "slide", direction: "left" });
},
```

Has anybody really faced a problem like this? I have no idea what to do right now as I was trying to resolve this issue for 2 days+.

**EDIT**

Basically I need to move across the pages defined as views. I define each view in different file containing properties: extend, requires, alias, config and methods defined by me. Every config property has titlebar attached as its first item.

When I'm trying to change page, I load another view by controller command which changes address hash. Routes controller then fires an animateActiveItem method which loads another View (defined previously as xtype by alias property).

I was using Miami Coder's Tutorial (miamicoder.com/2012/how-to-create-a-sencha-touch-2-app-part-1/) to learn Sencha Touch basics.

Comment: I think.the way you are adding view is wrong. If you can provide the details of what you want, I can help.

Comment: All I want is to move across my views (not cards) freely. I use routes to let application keep up with user's actions after page reload. I don't think it's crucial but I was trying to understand routes feature too.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean title bar and not toolbar...

Use navigation view to navigate between views instead of `Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem`
It is a better method. For using navigation view use this guide in sencha docs...
Sencha has a steep learning curve so be ready for frustrations like this...

[Navigation View Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/navigationview)

Comment: Thanks for your link. The problem is I'm not pretty sure if Navigation View is good enough for my application. What if I don't want the Sencha's auto-generated back button and want to replace it with something else? Also, what about routes and hardware back button in Android phones?

Comment: good question you can hide that custom title bar and create your own title bar i will write how to do that below

Comment: routes is like bookmarking feature it will only work for mobile browsers and not for an installed app... Android back button unfortunately means different things in different devices... In some it only gets out of the application in others it kills the application...

Answer (score 0):

You can add your required views in one panel class and enable the required view using

```
mainclass.setActiveItem(0)
```

or else use the navigation view

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    xtype: 'navigationview',
    id: 'navView',
    navigationBar: {
        hidden: true
    }

}
```

The above code will hide the title bar generated by navigation view... Now you need to define your own titlebar like so

```
{
       xtype: 'titlebar',
       title: 'title',
       items: [
            {
                   xtype: 'button',
                   text: 'back',
                   listeners: [
                     {
                         fn: function(button){
                              Ext.getCmp('navView').pop();//this will pop the view and show previous view
                         },event: 'tap'

                     }
                   ]
            }
       ]



}
```

Hope it helps...